# mvc 3 (maybe earlier) ViewData on page not been substituted its value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I do have one project in this solution where this works.

This project was started by copying that and renaming it.

This is in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(User user)
    {
        ViewData["debug"] = "hi ya!";
        return View();
    }
```

This is the page (index.aspx ~ this isn't cshtml):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="T30" TagPrefix="a" Namespace="Prj.T30.Html" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/template/MVC.master" Title="Material Moves" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<div>
    <input type="text" value="" id="Text1" />
    <br />
    ViewData["debug"]
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The page in the browser is the literal

> "ViewData["debug"]"

Why isn't it what I should be able to expect?

> "Hi ya!"

Thanks for your time, thoughts, and well wishes.

Comment: .. because you haven't wrapped it in `<% %>`?

Comment: I do that and intellisence tells me "ViewData" does not exists in current context.  And running the page errors/crashes "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:


Line 10:         <input type="text" value="" id="Text1" />
Line 11:         <br />
Line 12:         <% ViewData["debug"] %>
Line 13:     </div>
Line 14: "  so I add the ":" and get "Compiler Error Message: CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: Well, I can't remember the syntax but as you've seen if you don't wrap it it's displayed literally.

Comment: System.Web.Mvc reference is version 4.0.0.1 runtime version 4.0.30319

Comment: Are you importing the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` namespace in the view?

Comment: Thanks. I think that is nudge in the right direction.  What is that tag going to look like?  <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Mvc" Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %> ???  the documentation says ViewData is in "System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"

Comment: It isn't about adding a <% Register Assembly tag.  I have to add a Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" attribute to the <% Page tag.   But it still isn't working entirely yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @stuartd for the much needed nudge.

For the @ directives ~ load the ViewPage class in the Inherits attribute:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" MasterPageFile="~/template/MVC.master" Title="really moving stuff man" %>
```

For the page content:

```
<% =ViewData["debug"] %>
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <%@ Register Assembly="T30" TagPrefix="a" Namespace="Prj.T30.Html" %>
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"                   
    MasterPageFile="~/template/MVC.master" Title="Material Moves" %>
   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
   <div>
<input type="text" value="" id="Text1" />
<br />
@string vData= ViewData["debug"];
 @vData;
</div>
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your suggestion won't have the DataView object in the page will it?  You need to include System.Web.Mvc don't you?  For instance you could even on page as System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ViewData["debug"]